# To Do List using JQuery and LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, list

Hi guys I'm trying to create a TODO list using JQuery and Local Storage.

1. If the localstorage has values already, they should populate when
   the page loads (closing the window and reopening retains the
   "todo's")
2. If an item already exists in the list, show a console message noting the    duplicate (using $.inArray)
3. User should be able to add and remove items and have the changes save automatically (using splice)

This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
  <h1>TODO List</h1>
  <input id="input" type="text"><button id="add">Add</button>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
if(window.localStorage !== undefined){
var storeData = { };
var input = $("#input").val();
$("#add").click(function (){
  localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify(input));
});
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storeData"));
  $("#list").html(data);
});
</script>
```

Is something wrong in the code? How can I add the splice and check duplicates using $.inArray? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting to one key `input` and retrieving from a different key `storeData`

try changing

```
localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify(input));
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem("storeData", JSON.stringify(input));
```

If you are trying to store an array you need to rethink your `add` functionality. Right now all it will store is the value of the input when the page loads...which is likely empty. And you have no array to work from in your code

I suggest you look at code used in [todoMVC](http://todomvc.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! So if I want to store a list of items that the user added, how can I add each input into the array? Newbie in jquery, thanks!

Comment: use the same array name as the retrieve process. Then push to that array to add. Strongly suggest going through the source code of todoMVC